# Recommendation for a Download Manager for ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, software-recommendation

I've heard about:

- JDloader,
- [Uget [image]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/uget/),
- [Flareget [image]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/flareget/)
- etc.

But what are the pros and cons of these softwares?
Which one would you suggest to me to be the most reliable and fastest?

Thanks
Jye

Comment: @Akiva, question updated

Comment: I use Flareget. It has most of the features of the IDM. Has browser integration also.